# Using parent class logger in child class

Tags: c#, nlog

I have a base class for all controllers and the logger is defined there:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    private static readonly ILogger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

    protected ILogger Logger => logger;
}

public class ChildClass : BaseClass 
{
    public void DoStuff() 
    {
        Logger.Info("Some info");
    }
}
```

Now when I use `Logger` from a child class, the log entry shows BaseService as logger. Is there a way to tell the log manager to instantiate the logger for the child class?

Comment: Okay you should probably show how you write the log entry, if i'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @mybirthname - updated the question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is how you can do it:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    protected ILogger Logger => LogManager.GetLogger(this.GetType().FullName);
}
```

Please note that `GetLogger` caches the logger internally (for each different name) so that you don't create a new logger every time the `Logger` property is obtained.

The trick here is that `this.GetType().FullName` will return the name of the derived type, not `BaseService`.

Answer (score 0):

As more performant implementation would be:

```
public abstract class BaseService
{
    protected ILogger Logger { get; private set; }

    protected BaseService(Type type)
    {
        Logger = LogManager.GetLogger(type.FullName);
    }
}

public class ChildClass : BaseService
{
    public ChildClass()
        : base(typeof(ChildClass)) //fast
    {
    }

    public void DoStuff()
    {
        Logger.Info("Some info");
    }
}
```

as `typeof(ChildClass)` is compile-time known and `this.GetType().FullName` isn't.

Comment: This comes with the uglyness of having to explicitly get the type of the current class in all subclasses' constructors. This opens up for errors and leads to the same type of boiler plate code inheritance should eliminate.

Comment: It's a choice between performance and maintainability. There isn't a wrong dependency here, only some boilerplate. It's a correct implementation and a correct alternative. Maybe it's not needed for your case, but that doesn't mean you have to downvote it...